# Rewrite only a specific portion of a file in c#

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter, writer

I want to update the content of my csv, but I want to do it an other way than delete the whole content and write it again. Is there a way to rewrite a specific line in the csv file?
I am doing something like this at the moment:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("File.csv", string.Empty);
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("File.csv"))
{
  var writer = new CsvWriter(sw);             
   for (int i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++)
   {
      writer.WriteField(Values[i]);
      writer.NextRecord();
   }
}
```

Comment: While the question is good, the title is a little misleading.
So if i get this right, you want to overwrite only a specific portion of the file?

Comment: something like writer.Override(index, newValue)

Comment: If the length of what you overwrite (in bytes) stays the same, you can could overwrite it in principle. If the length changes you need to rewrite everything that comes after it.

Comment: But if you need to update specific lines, csv is probably not the right choice. A database might be a better fit. Or keeping the whole data in memory and writing it only out sequentially when the user presses the save button.

Comment: thank you, than i will use someting else than csv

Answer (score -1):

I use CsvHelper.
Something like :

```
 var csvFactory = new CsvFactory();
 using(var parser = csvFactory.CreateParser(reader, DefaultCsvConfiguration)){

    while(true){
       var arrayResult = parser.Read();

       if(arrayResult == null){
          break; //end of file
       }

       else{
          //DO THINGS WITH arrayResult
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? The question is about incremental updates, your answer is about reading.

Comment: Yeah sorry, read too fast. You can use CsvWriter really easily too : http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#writing

Comment: The OP's problem isn't simply writing CSV. It's incremental updates. Typical file systems which don't allow you to insert/remove bytes in the middle of a file inherently put severe restrictions on such updates.